# Beware: macOS Finder "Connect to Server" accepts FTPS URLs (FTP in a SSL/TLS tunnel) but actually connects via plain FTP!

Tags: finder, network, security, ftp, ssl

### Reproduction

- macOS 11 Big Sur
- Finder > Main Menu > Go > Connect to server… (⌘-K)
- Field allows ftps:// scheme. That is FTP in a SSL/TLS tunnel:
  [image: Finder > Connect To Server > FTPS protocol scheme]

### Questions

- Is Finder actually using FTPS?
- If so, which one?

  - Implicit FTPS (connecting to port 990)
  - Explicit FTPS (connecting to the regular FTP port 21 and then SSL/TLS handshake)?
- Will Finder ever fallback to FTP? If so, will it tell me?
- I would like to know this beforehand using it on a regular basis.

Answer (score 7):

### No! Beware: Even though you explicitly requested FTPS, Finder actually uses FTP !

- That is quite a horrible user experience in regards to https://apple.com/privacy/

  - Without telling the user, Finder simply falls back to FTP!
- I checked this via [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org):
  [image: FTPS address input in Finder is actually handled as plain FTP without telling the user]

## Apple documentation / feedback

- macOS 11 documentation on [Network address formats and protocols on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/network-address-formats-and-protocols-on-mac-mchlp1654/11.0/mac/11.0) just says:

> From the Finder, you can connect to FTP servers only with read-only access. To copy files to an FTP server, use an FTP app.

- So the documentation is correct. Promises nothing about FTPS nor mentions it anyhow.
- But Finder accepts FTPS input and transforms it to FTP without any warning!

  - If you also dislike this:

    - File feedback at the [given documentation page](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/network-address-formats-and-protocols-on-mac-mchlp1654/11.0/mac/11.0)
    - Or better file an issue at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

      - I filed to Apple and mirrored it at http://www.openradar.me/FB9224153

Comment: This sort of how to use Wireshark is always awesome - thanks for the alert on security

Comment: You're welcome! When I had already done the heavy research myself, I though I better share it with the Apple community. Thank you at StackExchange for offering and encouraging to "answer your own question". And yes Wireshark is great for getting real confirmation on network issues!